# Dynamically render a set of questions(received as API response), along with a text field and radio button under each question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components

Currently working on a Question/Answer page using ReactJS. I receive the questions via an API call.

What I would like to display is a set of radio buttons, and text field for the user to answer each of these questions. A "Panel" that looks roughly like this

[image: Panel description]

Incase, the above link doesnt work, i am looking for something like this.

---

"question 1 ......"
        "set of radio buttons"
         "text box"

"question 2 ......"
        "set of radio buttons"
         "text box"

---

However, The number of questions keep changing, hence i cannot assume a static number of panels/rows.

I tried using the map function to create an array of components. Something like this. P.S : Currently the component is just `<h1>` tags, I would need to change it to a `<form></form>` for my usecase.

```
var comdata = data.map((x, i) => {
            return (<h1>{x.data}</h1>)
          })
```

How, do i render this array of components?

Any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the map function seems like the correct way to go, you can separate into to two different components like this:

```
// In the future this would be your form for a single question
const QuestionForm = ({ data }) => (
   <h1>{data}</h1>
);

/**
 * Here you would create a component that maps the data and calls 
 * the previous component for each entry, make sure you provide a 
 * unique key to each element of the  array
 */
class Questionary extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const data = this.props;

      const questions = data.map(question => (
          <QuestionForm 
              key={question.id} 
              data={question.data} 
          />
      );

      return (
          <div className="questionary">
              <h1>Questionary</h1>
              {questions}
          </div>
      );
    }
);
```

In this case I used functional components, but if you use regular class components, just make sure you return your array of components in the render function.

Comment: Yep, this makes sense. Could you please help a beginnner out, and show what you mean by "return your array of components in the render function." 


I am using regulas class component, as i have to connect with redux. And was not sure how to use functional components for this.

Comment: @MASTERSHEFI just updated the Questionary component to something that might make more sense. You just need to make sure that you include your array of components somewhere in the return result of the render function. You can just return an array or a more complex JSX with the array within.

Answer (score 0):

You can render the radio button and text inside the map something like the below example

```
var Question = ({ data }) => (
          <h1>{data.title}</h1>
          {
            //map your radio buttons here if you get the options in the data
           data.options.map(option => <input type="radio"/>)
          }  
          <textarea/>
   )
```

In the render the above component can be used to with map and generate multiple questions

```
{ 
  data.map((x,i) => (
    <Question data={x} />
  ))    
}
```

Comment: Okay will try this out, but what exactly do i put in my return statement?

Comment: return in render?

Comment: yeah. in the render, return statement.

Comment: `render () {
   return(
      {
         data.map((x,i) => (
           <Question data={x} />
         ))
      }
   )
}`